# Change Default Installation Path - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have installed Windows 7 on my SSD, but I don't want my software to be installed on the SSD. I am trying to change the default installation path for both 32-bit and 64-bit software. I've been following a [guide](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-you-change-the-default-installation/73450b25-d794-4f18-9add-75253b893343) where I modify my registry the value ProgramFilesDir and ProgramFilesDir(x86) found at `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE|Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`. My question is what about modifying the other values such as CommonFilesDir, CommonW6432Dir, ProgramW6432Dir?

Comment: don't do this, it will break Windows (updates, upgrade).

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry, don't do what? Touch the ProgramFilesDir and (x86)?

Comment: yes, don't touch Program Files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't need to hack registry! Just make sure each new program is installed in custom mode which almost always allow you changing the installation path before proceeding. Custom mode is preferable as you have absolute control of what is installed, so you make sure you include all the application components, not only the basics as is the case with typical installation. Also you make sure no additional unwanted programs (eg Google toolbar) are installed along with the application. Just read carefully each message and make the right decisions before clicking next.

Comment: Softwares like Google Chrome don't allow you to choose. And that's just one example! Of course, I agree with what you said