# Windows 10 default installation drive not applied

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, installation, external-hard-drive

I have a fresh Windows 10 installation with a quite new version status 10.0.15014. The C drive is rather small which is why I'd like to use a MicroSD drive and/or external USB HDD as default installation drive for new software.

Windows 10 allows [customizing this setting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/cannot-change-install-location-of-apps-in-windows/fd9efca0-1b34-45de-bed9-e9b42b24aaae) since some earlier version. And I was able to change the drive letters accordingly. This has created a specific directory on the destination drive.

But installing software still puts it onto the C drive. I have tried Google Chrome, Dropbox, and Office 365. Most of them do not even provide a custom installation anymore which would allow to change the destination folder.

How can I enforce the applied setting? There might be some additional possibilities involving manual [registry changes](https://superuser.com/questions/556530/change-default-installation-path-windows-7). But I'd like to evade them as long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You've assumed something that is a common misconception.

Apps and software are not the same thing.

Apps are everything that automatically gets installed when downloaded through the windows store.

All other software that has a setup will most of the time allow you to choose where to install the software. By default it will use %programfiles% and its x86 counterpart as default directory, allowing you to browse to a different folder during the install, when you choose for a custom install.

Now, that said, it is possible to change the %programfiles% variable so that it automatically suggests the correct new path during install. The problem is that not every software respects this and may still have the c:\program files path hardcoded into the installer with an option to browse to a different folder, so its never going to be a 100% guaranteed fix.

But more importantly, its not recommended to do this because it can break windows. For example, if you only alter the %program files% path, some programs may suddenly expect that their location is on the new place while it is not. If you move the entire program files folder off to the D drive, windows components are likely to break, amongst Windows Update.

It is possible to get this to work by using a directory junction, but given the process that is required to get this to work is outside of the scope of this question, and can break your entire windows if not done correctly. It is only for the advanced user who doesn't mind reinstall windows if it breaks.